# how to get tab autocompletion to echo all possible options like bash?

Tags: powershell

In bash there's a nice feature that when a string is partially completed (like a path) and we use tab for autocompletion, we get ALL the possible options echoed out at once to aid the next character we might want to type.

In PowerShell, it just cycles through one option at a time, so you are relatively blind where numerous possibilities are involved.

Is equivalent behaviour possible in PowerShell?

Comment: You write something and then press CTRL+Space or Tab and that works? I don't understand in what context you're asking the question

Comment: I usually do `set-psreadlineoption -editmode emacs`, but that changes control-v too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler) to redefine what happens when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> as follows:

```bash
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Tab MenuComplete
```

Note that you'll have to add this command to your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) in order to make it take effect in future sessions too.

---

The **behavior of the [`MenuComplete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline_functions#menucomplete) function** is as follows:

- If there is *no* possible completion, no action is taken.
- If there is only *one* possible completion, it is performed instantly, in-line.
- If there are *two or more* possible completions, an *interactive menu* of the possible completions is shown below the input line:<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the *arrow keys* to cycle through the completions and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select one, which completes what was typed based on that selection and closes the menu.

    - Alternatively, *continue typing*, which prefix-matches against the parameter names and shrinks the menu dynamically (delete characters to expand it again).
  - Note that the highlighted menu item also shows that parameter's *data type* below the menu.

    - Once a parameter name has been completed, if you want data-type information *plus* a verbal description of that parameter, you can use the [`ShowParameterHelp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline_functions#showparameterhelp) function, available in PowerShell (Core) 7.2+, which is bound to <kbd>Alt+h</kbd> by default.

---

**Additional [`PSReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline) tips:**

- To see a **list of available functions**:

  - Consult the [`about_PSReadLine_Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline_functions) help topic; if it isn't available locally (with `Get-Help about_PSReadLine_Functions`), run `Update-Help -Module PSReadLine`.
  - To list all functions grouped by functional category, using [`Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline/get-psreadlinekeyhandler):

    ```bash
    Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Bound -Unbound
    ```
  - To see a flat list sorted by function name instead:

    ```bash
    Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Bound -Unbound |
      Sort-Object Function |
      Select-Object Function, Key, Description
    ```
- To **check what key chord(s) a given function is currently bound to**:

  ```bash
  # This example looks for function names that contain the word "menu"
  # Use -eq with a full function name, if known.
  Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler | Where-Object Function -like *Menu*
  ```
- To **discover what function is currently bound to a given key chord**:

  - Use the [`WhatIsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline_functions#whatiskey) function, which on Windows is bound to <kbd>Alt+?</kbd> by default; on Unix-like platforms, where the range of usable key chords is limited, there is no default binding, but you can define one as follows, using `Alt+w` as an example:

    ```bash
    Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Alt+w WhatIsKey
    ```
  - Pressing the key chord that `WhatIsKey` is bound to then prompts for pressing the key chord of interest, which, if it is bound, prints the bound function name and its description.

---

<sup>[1] The possible completions are *not* shown in *alphabetical* order; instead, the order appears to be based on the parameter definition order, combined with some additional logic: an exact match is listed first, alias names are listed *after* their original names, dynamic parameters are listed after static ones, and matching [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) names come last.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it, @openCivilisation; my pleasure.